# extract the 4th filed of structure file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have matlab data 1x617 stuct with 1 field and each row has 1x1 struct with 4 fields. How can I extract the data to get the 4th field for 617 data, the 4th field is nx1 double. Thanks

Comment: It is hard to understand the over all structure could you try to write as tree/folder structure. This might even help you better understand the problem.

Comment: the data that I have is 'diffAnalysisRes1' 1x617 struct with 1 field, each row is 'diffAnalysisRes1(1).fullDim' to  'diffAnalysisRes1(617).fullDim'  1x1struct with 4 fields. I want to collect the 4th field fine name is ' diffAnalysisRes1(1).fullDim.normDiffCoef' to  'diffAnalysisRes1(617).fullDim.normDiffCoef'. I am hoping to have a command that collect all the 4th field for 617 data Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your variable structure, it can be sometimes easily solved by simply index reference it. However, in your case that you want to collect data from one specific field within array of struct variable, I would recommend to use `structval` on Matlab FileExchange

Here is the link:

[Struct 2 array or cell for desiginated fieldname](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50534-struct-2-array-or-cell-for-desiginated-fieldname%20sss)

Let's assume your variable looks like this

```
for idx = 1:617
    b.a = ones(1,1)*idx;
    b.b = ones(2,1)*idx;
    b.c = ones(3,1)*idx;
    b.d = ones(4,1)*idx;
    s(1,idx).a = b;
end
```

The above code creates a 1x617 stuct with 1 field, and each row has 1x1 struct with 4 fields. And here I assume that the name of the 4th field in each row is the same.

Now use `structval`

```
r = structval(s,'d');
```

The result is a **1x617** cell array. If you happen to have same size for that field at each index (e.g. a **nx1** array), then use

```
r = structval(s,'d','collapse',true);
```

to return a **nx617** array

Comment: Hi Steven, I have tried msd=stuctval(diffAnalysisRes1,diffAnalysisRes1.fullDim.normDiffCoef)
but it matlab  Undefined function or variable 'structval'. my data is 1x617 struct 1 field (filename is "diffAnalysisRes1") each row has 1x1 struct with 4 fields I want to collect all of the 4th data for 617 (file name "diffAnalysis1(1).fullDim.normDiffCoef" to "diffAnalysis1(617).fullDim.normDiffCoef"

Comment: `structval` is not a build-in function. It's a free distributed function on Matlab's File Exchange. You must first download `structval` from file exchagne and place it in your working directory. And note that your second argument to that function must be a string variable (see my example).  So it could looks like **structval(diffAnalysisRes1,'normDiffCoef')**

Comment: @PutuDewi If my answer solved your problem in the way you like, please kindly choose it for the best answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Steven, By any chance do you know a code, if I have 1x793 struct i field, each row axb a/b could be 1,2...etc. I want to count how many for b1,b2,b3.... and I ignore the value a. thanks

Comment: I've read 3 times but still don't understand what you were descripting. Maybe you should give an example of the `struct` may looks like. BTW, if just do count, isn't that something like a simple `for` loop can solve for you?

Comment: in workspace i have data "tracks1" 1x1261 struct with 1 field  each row ex: row1= 1x61 double, row2=1x30 double, row3=6x61 double, row 4=[40,45,43], row5= 50.....row1261=177. I want to count how many for nx61, nx60,...to nx1 (like row5=50, and row1261). I expect i will get  300 counts for nx61, 200 for nx60......50 for nx1. so i will have total 1261 counts. Thanks

Comment: It's very simple. First find the size of all array and store them in a `n x 2` array. Convert it to a table and then use `unique`.